# Proving Weierstrass Approximation Theorem on just bounded sets in $\mathbb R$

Tags: real-analysis, approximation-theory

> Suppose $f$ is a continuous function on $\mathbb R$. Show that we can approximate $f$ uniformly by a sequence of polynomials on any bounded subset of $\mathbb R$.

My attempt is as follows:

> $f$ being continuous on $\mathbb R$ is finite valued and well-defined at all points in $\mathbb R$, in particular on any bounded subset. Now consider any sequence of compact intervals converging to that subset. Then for each such compact interval, consider a sequence of polynomials converging to $f$ uniformly.

I am stuck after this...is this even the correct approach? Can we use the concept of Power Series or Taylor Series here? If so, how?

Comment: Can't you consider an approximation of $f$ on a compact set that includes the bounded subset?

Comment: Every bounded subset of $\mathbb {R}$ is contained in some $[a,b].$ By Weierstrass, you can approximate $f$ uniformly on $[a,b]$ by polynomials. Well, that works for the whole interval, hence is works for any subset of that interval.

Comment: Damn! Was approaching the problem in a totally wrong way!!